# C#, Visual Studio 2022 : create Index for SQL Server database with multiple conditions

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm [trying to create an index with multiple conditions](https://dbfiddle.uk/T1Jy3-bc), but got an error in my condition when using the **OR** operator.

> Msg 156 Level 15 State 1 Line 3
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OR'.

How can I do something like that?

```
CREATE INDEX [IX_DealInfos_IssuerCountry_IssuerRegionStr]
ON [CardTransactions].[DealInfo] ([IssuerCountry],[IssuerRegionStr])
WHERE IssuerCountry IS NULL 
   OR IssuerRegionStr IS NULL 
   OR IssuerCountry = '' OR ...
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Does this post help in any way? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68569522/sql-server-filtered-index-with-multiple-columns-in-where-clause.

Comment: OP and upvoter perhaps need a refresher of [ask].

Comment: I know this may be dated a little, there's a good article written by Brent Ozar, [What You Can (and Can’t) Do With Filtered Indexes](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/11/what-you-can-and-cant-do-with-filtered-indexes/)

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/65NVMMWW Use AND instead of OR

Comment: Or in indexes isn't supported. You could create a indexed view with this where condition and index it as alternative

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to get a similar behaviour using a persisted computed column with your logic in original table.

```
ALTER TABLE [CardTransactions].[DealInfo] 
ADD _Calculated_Issuer_Conditions 
AS 
CASE 
    WHEN ISNULL(IssuerCountry, '')='' THEN 1
    WHEN IssuerRegionStr IS NULL THEN 2
    WHEN [some_other_condition] THEN 3
    ELSE 0
END
PERSISTED
```

But it is not possible to create a filtered index on a computed column, so
once added, you need to create a schema-bound view on the table filtered on the computed column.

```
CREATE VIEW [CardTransactions].[v_DealInfo] 
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT *
FROM [CardTransactions].[DealInfo]
WHERE _Calculated_Issuer_Conditions > 0;
```

Now add a clustered index on the view to persist the values of computed column (I suppose you have PK on your `DealInfo` table, something like an Issuer ID, you can use it) and also a standard index on the computed column of the view

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX PK_v_DealInfo
ON [CardTransactions].[v_DealInfo](Issuer_ID);

CREATE INDEX IX_v_DealInfo_Calculated_Issuer_Conditions
ON [CardTransactions].[v_DealInfo](_Calculated_Issuer_Conditions);
```

Finally, when you use the view remember to add `WITH (NOEXPAND)` hint if you are not running on Enterprise edition

```
SELECT *
FROM [CardTransactions].[v_DealInfo] WITH (NOEXPAND)
WHERE _Calculated_Issuer_Conditions = CAST(1 AS INT)
```

Note the final cast of 1 as `INT` only to be sure the optimizer can match the datatypes.

This shoud do the trick